# add shadow effect as innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, shadow

would like to add in a shadow around the right side and bottom to give a 3d effect(see below)

not sure on how to do this...any help or a start would be great. so far my pop up is created inside a DIV and passed back as an innerHTML

Comment: Why does it have to be innerHTML? Can't you use CSS box-shadow, which is intended for this?

Comment: the desired effect is for innerHTML just the way it is coded atm

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CSS `box-shadow` property:

- [CSS Tricks - CSS Box Shadow](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)
- [CanIUse - CSS3 Box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow)
- [CSS Box Shadow Generator](http://css-shadow.com/)
- [W3C - CSS `box-shadow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow)

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps,

```
http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/
```

or this:

```
http://www.paulund.co.uk/creating-different-css3-box-shadows-effects
```

All the best!

Comment: Just wondered why the vote down...? the pages provided give you a CSS editor to achieve the exact effect you are looking for.